# Most efficient way to insert large number of items with typeorm

Tags: mysql, query-performance, typeorm

Does anyone know which is the most efficient way to insert large number of items with typeorm ?
Currently I am using the `save` method with `{ chunk: 500 }` option but it is very slow

The object I am passing in contains 1 row to a parent table and >35000 rows (child array) to a child table

If I slice the child array to 1000 objects then the insert takes about 10 seconds

Thanks,
Jani

Comment: "typeorm"?  Must be yet-anther-3rd-party package.  If you can provide the generated SQL statements, I might be able to advise you (or typoeorm).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reaching out, I am posting here the answer partly to my own question.
I am trying to insert 1 row in a header table and > 35000 rows in a child table. The children then have a reference to the parent record. This is the only solution I came up with:

```
await getConnection().createQueryBuilder().insert().into(MetadataSearch).values(metadataSearch).execute();
        metadataSearch.items.forEach(item => {
            item.metadataSearch = {
                id: metadataSearch.id
            };
        });
await getConnection().createQueryBuilder().insert().into(Item).values(metadataSearch.items).execute();
```

MetadataSearch is the parent table and Item the child table
The forEach loop is setting the parent id to the child records

Inserting the >35000 child records is really fast